# Conditional valdiation of required fields

Tags: javascript, validation

I have a page where the user enters their address. I want to make city, state and zip code required fields, but here's the catch. Either the user is required to enter both the city and the state OR they are required to enter the zip code. How do I do this javascript?

For now I have

```
function Form(f) {

    for (var n = 0; n < f.elements.length; n++) {

        if ((f.elements[n].name).indexOf("zip_code") > -1) {

            var zipcode = f.elements[n].value;

            if (zipcode.length == "") {

                if ((f.elements[n].name).indexOf("cityname") > -1) {

                    var city = f.elements[n].value;


                    if (city.length == "") {
                        alert("Enter City name");
                        break;
                    }

                }

                if ((f.elements[n].name).indexOf("statename") > -1) {

                    var state = f.elements[n].value;


                    if (state.length == "") {
                        alert("Enter State name");
                        break;
                    }

                }

            } else {
                //return true; then do something
                return false;
            }

        } else if (zipcode.length == "") {
            alert("Enter zipcode");
            break;

            return false;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please try this?

```
  function Form(f) {

     var cityname = document.getElementsByName('cityname')[0].value;

     var statename = document.getElementsByName('statename')[0].value;

     var zip_code = document.getElementsByName('zip_code')[0].value;

    if( (cityname.length==0 && statename.length==0 ) ){

         if(zip_code.length==0){
            alert("Enter zipcode");         
            return false;
          }  
      return true;
     }else if( (cityname.length==0 || statename.length==0 ) ){

        if (cityname.length == 0) {
              alert("Enter City name");              
              return false;             
           }else if (statename.length == 0) {
              alert("Enter State name");                  
              return false;             
          }

          return true;
      }  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should help

```
if( zipcode.length){
    /* validate zipcode*/
}else{
    if( city.length && state.length){

     }else{
         /* must have city and state*/
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use a variable flag.
flag = 0;

```
if city and state 
 make flag as 1
if zip 
 make flag as 1
if flag==0 then validation failed
else allow to submit form
```

Comment: -1: The OP requests JavaScript, not pseudocode. I'd understand if this was a homework question and showed no effort on part of the OP, but that isn't the case here.